# Gerrit/NoteDB User Management

Tags: gerrit

I am in the process of switching the LDAP backend that we use to authenticate access to Gerrit.

When a user logs in via LDAP, a local account is created within Gerrit. We are running version 2.15 of Gerrit, and therefore our local user accounts have migrated from the SQL DB into NoteDB.

The changes in our infrastructure, mean that once the LDAP backend has been switched, user logins will appear to Gerrit as new users and therefore a new local account will be generated. As a result we will need perform a number of administrative tasks to the existing local accounts before and after migration.

The REST API exposes some of the functionality that we need, however two key elements appear to be missing:

- There appears to be no way to retrieve a list of all local accounts through the API (such that I could then iterate through to perform the administrative tasks I need to complete). The /accounts/ endpoint insists on a query filter being specified, which does not appear to include a way to simply specify 'all' or '*'. Instead I am having to try and think of a search filter that will reliably return all accounts - I haven't succeeded yet.
- There appears to be no way to delete an account. Once the migration is complete, I need to remove the old accounts, but nothing is documented for the API or any other method to remove old accounts.

Has anybody found a solution to either of these tasks that they could share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that the answers to my questions were:

('/a/' in the below examples is accessing the administrative endpoint and so basic Auth is required and the user having appropriate permissions)

**Retrieving all accounts**

There is no way to do this in a single query, however combining the results of:

```
GET /a/accounts?q=is:active&n=<number larger than the number of users>
GET /a/accounts?q=is:inactive&n=<number larger than the number of users>
```

will give effectively the same thing.

**Deleting an account**

Seems that this simply is not supported. The only option appears to be to set an account inactive:

```
DELETE /a/accounts/<account_id>/active
```